# Translation of an old paper by Frobenius

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, translation-request, mathematical-german

I have an old paper:

- Frobenius, G. (1902). *Uber primitive Gruppen des Grades $n$ und der Klasse $n - 1$*. S. B. Akad. Berlin 1902, 455-459.

in the German language. Is there a way to access a translation of it? Or other proof in the English books or papers?

Comment: For completeness, the 1902 Sitzungsberichte volume can be found in free digital form at archive.org (https://archive.org/details/sitzungsberichte1902deutsch) in various formats; the paper itself can be read on that site [here](https://archive.org/stream/sitzungsberichte1902deutsch#page/455/mode/1up).